# Rails with ReactJS - realtime data fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Can I fetch the data from the my database in realtime using Rails and ReactJS?

I have just started using React with Rails as this is pretty awesome combination. What I want to know is if there is a way to tell the view to update itself after a component is deleted/ created (so a record is removed/ added to the database)? Something like user after entering the page will subscribe to the database event (?).

What I have now is `ComponentContainer` with a custom fetch method that gets json from the server. I put it in the `componentWillMount` and inside a `setInterval` and run it every single second:

```
var ComponentsContainer = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchRecords();
        setInterval(this.fetchRecords, 1000);
    },
    fetchRecords() {
        $.getJSON(path_to_results,
            (data) => this.setState({components: data});
    }, ...render methods etc.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might be looking for [`ActionCable`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html), a Rails 5 thing. It uses sockets to provide server/client communication and will enable the server to send or broadcast messages to clients.